# When using nuxt + ts with koa and run "dev" commond, the console tells me compile errors in Vue files which use typescript syntax

Tags: typescript, vue.js, nuxt.js, koa, nodemon

- nuxt: 2.6.2
- node: 16.5.0
- koa: 2.7.0

my `package.json` file :

```
{
    ...
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development nodemon server/index.ts --watch server --exec babel-node --presets @babel/preset-env"
    }
}
```

**How it shows:**

After run "yarn dev` commond, and it begins to work:

- The first step of compiling and running the KOA server has passed, and then ask me `Are you interested in participating?`, I choose `yes`.
- Then it begins to complie Nuxt web server, but now the console tell me `ERROR  Failed to compile with 3 errors`. I looked through the questions and saw that they were all related to TS in my Vue page or Component, such as :

```
Module parse failed: Unexpected character '@' (11:0)                                                                                                                                                                                                           friendly-errors 23:08:49
File was processed with these loaders:
 * ./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/index.js
You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders.
| import {Vue, Component} from 'vue-property-decorator';
|
> @Component
| export default class GlobalLayout extends Vue {
|
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               friendly-errors 23:08:49
 @ ./layouts/GlobalLayout.vue?vue&type=script&lang=ts& 1:0-124 1:140-143 1:145-266 1:145-266
 @ ./layouts/GlobalLayout.vue
 @ ./.nuxt/App.js
 @ ./.nuxt/index.js
 @ ./.nuxt/client.js
 @ multi ./node_modules/eventsource-polyfill/dist/browserify-eventsource.js (webpack)-hot-middleware/client.js?reload=true&timeout=30000&ansiColors=&overlayStyles=&path=%2F__webpack_hmr%2Fclient&name=client ./.nuxt/client.js
```

- At last, the console can print out the console.log code which I write in `server/index.ts`. So maybe we can prove that by use `nodemon` to start the whole server instead of `nuxt` can make some typescript compile errors? Because  if I just run `nuxt` directly, it can compile successfully without any errors, when I use Koa and change dev comond, it makes some errors.

#### The sample code

I try to reslove this problem and find it on web. I just find a repository which use nuxt + ts+ koa and very similar to mine.

[sample code](https://github.com/negibouze/nuxt-koa-ts)

`https://github.com/negibouze/nuxt-koa-ts`

I clone it and run on my machine but it makes the same errors with mine, so you can clone it and run.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like TS requires something else to work.
I've cloned the sample project, installed all the packages, then installed those packages globally too: https://typestrong.org/ts-node/docs/installation

And it worked fine.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I use another computer to clone and run it, it works well but with some warnings `"export 'default' (imported as 'mod') was not found in '-!../node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js??ref--3-0!../node_modules/ts-loader/index.js??ref--3-1!../node_modules/vue-loader/lib/index.js??vue-loader-options!./Logo.vue?vue&type=script&lang=ts&'`.

Comment: I find it use an old version of nuxtjs, I update to the latest 2.15.8 and the compile errors show again. I try to install global as you said, but it not works.

Comment: I find an answer which relate to the same error, [github issue](https://github.com/nuxt-community/nuxt-property-decorator/issues/62). It seems like that I need to use `nuxt-ts` instead of `nuxt`, but if I use koa in nuxt, the dev commond has no `nuxt`, how can I solve it ?

Comment: Any more help, sir?

Comment: @EdenSheng I'm not a TS expert so I don't know how to debug it quickly enough. You should probably try to narrow down the issue by testing several configurations and setups to find out how to make this work.

Comment: Tks four your answer. I just find some way to solve this problem and have some tries. The latest nuxtjs version contains ts complie so that only use `nuxt` instead of `nuxt-ts`, then I find a official issue about it to solve this problem: [github issue](https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/issues/5508). Firstly add or change `"target": "esnext","module": "esnext"` to `tsconfig.json`. Secondly, change the `export default` to `module.export = ` in `nuxt.config.js` or `nuxt.config.ts`. It works fine!

Comment: @EdenSheng does it work so? Feel free to post your own answer here and to accept it!

Comment: @EdenSheng feel free to post your own answer.